# 17.04 all system icons turn into boxes and all applications become unresponsive

Tags: 17.04, crash

I just upgraded to 17.04 and I am having a problem where every few hours all my applications stop functioning properly (terminal cannot recognize any files, Firefox cannot load any more pages) and all of the icons in the top bar turn into boxes. In addition all of the icons in the tray on the left side are not present. I am unable to shut down the computer without manually holding the power button for 5 seconds and sometimes after this happens I have a problem where the computer cannot find my boot loader.

I used to dual boot with Windows 10 but just today I installed a fresh 17.04 over all of my partitions.

Sorry if this is a repeat question, I find it hard to describe all of the symptoms that I am having.

My computer is an HP Envy 15T-AS000. As you can see in the top right corner all the system notification icons are boxes.

[image]

Here is a picture of my memory check.

[image]

Comment: 17.10 isn't supported here. Sorry.

Comment: I misspoke, I have 17.04. I edited my question

Comment: I think some icon pack is missing. Try runing sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade in terminal and reboot.

Comment: I have just done so. I believe that the problem is outside the icon pack as I am unable to run any terminal commands if I have a terminal window open (for example, I get unrecognized command when I run `ls`)

Comment: Sorry, dont have other advise. But if my Ubuntu wasn't able to run commands, I would not think a second and reinstall.

Answer (score 3):

If these problems occur only when the laptop is running on battery power, then maybe the battery is worn out and it needs to be replaced. If these problems occur only when the laptop is running on power from the power adapter, then maybe the power adapter needs to be replaced or the adapter cable is damaged or there is a bad electrical connection to the adapter.

Before you spend money on replacing the power adapter, you can take your laptop to a computer repair shop and try renting one of their adapters.

HP Memory test that is part of the System diagnostics is sufficient to test if the memory is working properly.

Comment: Would the HP "Memory test" that is part of the `System diagnostics` be sufficient?

Comment: I have added a link to a picture of what the memory test looks like